# Surge.SH / Node JS - Self signed certificate in chain

Tags: node.js, npm, surge.sh

I am using Surge.sh to deploy my simple website and this error appears on my command prompt

```
Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1538:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:952:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:733:12) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I am struggling here for months now. Do you guys have the same problem? How do you fix it? Thanks in advance.